# If else statement without the else?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I was given this code and it has an If statement with two sets of curly brackets. I'm assuming it's an if else statement, but there is no 'else'

```
if (Value.Contains("WMD ESA"))
{
   UsersInfo.Add(Benefit.ToString());
}
{
   UsersInfo.Add(((decimal)Benefit.Amount().ToString());
}
```

according to my break points this runs fine without any errors So I'm not sure.

Comment: Although it's impossible for me to know, that looks suspiciously like a missing `else`. As mentioned in an answer, the presence of those brackets creates uncertainty. There's nothing like seeing something that works and suspecting that it doesn't do what it's supposed to, but you can't tell. If there was a passing unit test that verified the expected behavior that would clear it up.

Comment: There is no point trying to see if it's broken or not, we can't possibly know that. You should talk to the people in your team, dig out the requirements and run some tests to see if the code works as it should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just an arbitrary code block. The curly braces here do nothing; they can be removed. It's functionally the same as the following:

```
if (Value.Contains("WMD ESA"))
{
   UsersInfo.Add(Benefit.ToString());
}

UsersInfo.Add(((decimal)Benefit.Amount().ToString());
```

IMO they *should* be removed if this is intended, as it's pretty confusing (and uncommon in my experience). Although just make sure that an `else` was not intended!

Comment: Interesting. I'll leave for now since this program is in production and I dont want to break anything.

Comment: @AustinGarrison - the thing is, this is so uncommon that I'd put my money on an else statement missing here. This might actually *be* broken in production. It would probably be worthwhile looking it over with a peer if you're unable to verify with complete certainty that this is indeed intended.

Comment: We went back a couple months and looked at a previous version, Indeed the else is missing.

Comment: This is not exactly true. The seemingly extraneous `{...}` introduces a new namespace scope. In this particular case it is an empty scope.

Comment: @NicholasCarey - That's true. Although in (all?) the cases I've come across, where it's only the `{...}`, it has either been a mistake/typo (like here), or a developer of a different "era"/background thought it was "safer" - which was fun to push back on...

Answer (score 0):

To understand and solve your problem, you must learn how a statement work.

> **Statement :**
>
> Common actions include declaring variables, assigning values, calling methods, looping through collections, and branching to one or another block of code, depending on a given condition.
>
> **Different Type Of Statement**
>
> - Declaration statements  .
> - Expression statements .
> - **Selection statements** .
> - Iteration statements .
> - Jump statements .
> - Exception handling statements .
> - Checked and unchecked .
>
> In this case we are using **Selection statements** .

**Code :**

Curly braces are generally used to impart a scope but they are optional.

If we inspect your code we have a first if with braces , any object declared inside the if braces will be visible only inside the scope of the if , for the second braces there is any statement automatically they will belong to the parent scope.

**code 1 :**

```
 if (Value.Contains("WMD ESA"))
 {
     UsersInfo.Add(Benefit.ToString());
 }
 {
     UsersInfo.Add(((decimal)Benefit.Amount().ToString());
 }
```

**code 2 :**

```
 if (Value.Contains("WMD ESA"))
 {
     UsersInfo.Add(Benefit.ToString());
 }

 UsersInfo.Add(((decimal)Benefit.Amount().ToString());
```

As consclusion the code 1 and code 2 are logically equivalent .